# SQL function delete rows with a specific date and a specific value on another column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a question, mostly about syntax.

I have a sql table and I need to delete some rows based on the date on a "Date" column as long as they contain a string in a "Client" column

My issue is the syntax since I am not that knowledgeable in query.

```
    DELETE FROM [dbo].[ClientList]
    WHERE [Date]
   BETWEEN '2019-09-30'  AND '2019-10-01'
```

is an example, but how do I add besides that condition a condition such as

```
Where [Client]
LIKE 'CLIENT1'
```

it is a simple question but cant find an example of 2 conditions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `AND`:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[ClientList]
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN '2019-09-30' AND '2019-10-01' AND
      [Client] LIKE 'CLIENT1'
```

Comment: Thank you, I know it was simple but was unsure of the syntax.!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the AND keyword so that both the conditions are satisfied during deletion

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[ClientList]
WHERE [Date]
BETWEEN '2019-09-30'  AND '2019-10-01'
AND
[Client] LIKE 'CLIENT1'
```